# Why are my Django / uWSGI vassal logs empty?

Tags: python, django, logging, debian, uwsgi

I am running my Django site as a vassal of UWSGI emperor. I have created `/etc/uwsgi-emperor/vassals/mysite.ini` as follows:

```
[uwsgi]
socket = /var/opt/mysite/uwsgi.sock
chmod-socket = 775
chdir = /opt/mysite
master = true
virtualenv = /opt/mysite_virtualenv
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings
module = mysite.wsgi:application
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
processes = 1
threads = 1
plugins = python3,logfile
logger = file:/var/log/uwsgi/app/mysite.log
vacuum = true
```

But `/var/log/uwsgi/app/mysite.log` does not get created. If I `touch` it, it remains empty. This occurs even after I trigger 500-style errors in the application.

Why aren't my logs being written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vassal does not have permission to write to the file (or create the file in the first place). You should

```
cd /var/log/uwsgi/app
touch mysite.log # create the file
chown www-data:www-data mysite.log # give the vassal permission
```

(where www-data:www-data matches the uid and gid values in your ini file).

Logs will start appearing shortly.